# auto create stackView from array count

Tags: swift, uitableview, auto-generate, stackview

Please tell me if I chose the right approach or are there other options?

I receive an array of objects from the server.

According to the task I have to place each object of the array in the table cell

How many objects will come I don’t know, I just mean that they all have the same structure and that they should be placed automatically.

I chose the path - stack view
Is there any easy way to automatically generate their number?

And whether I think correctly...

I need to create 1n total stack in the cell and transfer new stack to inside

there is response from server

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9ebed4100d4d4db49aab728a16ac693d

each array must be a cell

inside each array - the array is a data set that should be automatically insert .... 
maybe in the stack?

Comment: Please share code for better explanation. But I think you can set another tableView in your main tableView cell.

Comment: update main massage

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableView. It will be better choise

**upd:**
Use complex UITableView with sections.
Also some like this can help you: https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429

Comment: thanks, I already made a new tableView inside the cell

But what approach should I choose to automatically fill the cells with data from arrays?

if you carefully examine the unicard, you can see that in addition to generating the cells, it also means that they are filled with data.
image, title and value

it also passes statuses
the field with title and value must be full or half full of cell

and the most important

There can be a lot of such fields.

Comment: Or do you propose to create another 1n view inside an automatically generated cell and use it already to generate other cells with a value?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that you want to fill cell.